# JavaScript Tic-Tac-Toe check if someone won

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I wrote a little program which is supposed to let me play Tic-Tac-Toe.
But now i'm stuck because I dont know how I'm supposed to check if someone won or not..

My "Playground" where you put the Circle and the Cross is made out of 9 divs.
I made this array with the Winning Options:

```
const winnercombinations = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [1,5,9],
    [3,5,7],
    [1,4,7],
    [2,5,8],
    [3,6,9],
];
```

And this is how my checkwin function looks so far (pretty much empty):

```
function checkwin(){
    if(indexOf("") == )

    if()

    if()

    else{
        alert("Player One and Player Two tied the game.")
    }

}
```

I dont know if you need it to answer my question but here a little example of how my Divs look like:

```
<div class="gameboard">
    <div class="layout" id="firstdiv" onclick=play(this);></div>
    <div class="layout" id="seconddiv" onclick=play(this);></div>
    <div class="layout" id="thirddiv" onclick=play(this);></div>
    <div class="layout" id="fourthdiv" onclick=play(this);></div>
    <div class="layout" id="fifthdiv" onclick=play(this);></div>
    <div class="layout" id="sixthdiv" onclick=play(this);></div>
    <div class="layout" id="seventhdiv" onclick=play(this);></div>
    <div class="layout" id="eightdiv" onclick=play(this);></div>
    <div class="layout" id="ninthdiv" onclick=play(this);></div>
</div>
```

I need to check if my Divs are in one of the winnercombination orders? And if yes -> someone won, and if that's not the case -> game tied.

Here my play function since it might be necesarry for you to answer my question:

```
function play(clickedDiv){
    clickedDiv.onclick = "";
    clickedDiv.innerHTML = "<span>" + zeichen[weristdran] + "</span>";
    toggle();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would suggest you click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58113438/edit), then the stacksnippet editor `[<>]` and provide a [mcve] of your issue

Comment: 1. What's in your `play`-function? 2. Please use loops to check if the player has won after the last move. Tic-Tac-Toe is a perfect simple example for loops!

Comment: That might be the problem, I dont have a loop in my play function..

Comment: To make the questions better received, I would focus on the problem (like "How to implement Tic-Tac-Toe patterns in JS array?" - without the HTML part. It is better if the question can be useful to other people solving similar problems.

Comment: @JanTuroň I don't think it's the HTML part. It's the half-baked code. It's not even pseudo-code, which is pretty much "do this for me". Also, to OP I was writing an article a while back on progressing through tic-tac-toe as you become more proficient. What you end up with on the route you're on is this: https://codepen.io/zfrisch/pen/ObKZVV  - you'll quickly learn that you need to think about the design before hammering down the pieces. Tic-Tac-Toe seems simple, but it spaghettis out into if-else statements galore if you let it. It's a learning experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a game, you should create a **model** for it, which contains the data, and separate it from design. In your case:

```
<div class="gameboard">
    <div class="layout" data-index="0"></div>
    <div class="layout" data-index="1"></div>
    <div class="layout" data-index="2"></div>
    <div class="layout" data-index="3"></div>
    <div class="layout" data-index="4"></div>
    <div class="layout" data-index="5"></div>
    <div class="layout" data-index="6"></div>
    <div class="layout" data-index="7"></div>
    <div class="layout" data-index="8"></div>
</div>
```

Now hook click events to the fields:

```
var fields = document.querySelectorAll(".layout");
for(let i=0; i<fields.length; ++i) fields[i].onclick = function(e) {
  e.target.innerHTML = model.update(e.target.dataset.index);
}
```

This answers your question how to check the winner combination: it is the model business. Before we prepare the model (including the `model.update` function above), let's prepare gameover function:

```
var game = {
  won: function(player, row) {
    alert("Player "+player+ " won at "+row.toString());
  }
}
```

To this point, we were doing the game design. Now we add the game logic in the model, separated from the design:

```
var model = {
  player: "X",
  data: ["","","","","","","","",""],
  update: function(pos) {
    if(model.data[pos]=="") model.data[pos] = model.player;
    model.player = model.player=="X" ? "O" : "X";
    model.checkWinner();
    return model.data[pos];
  },
  checkWinner: function() {
    const combos = [
        [0,1,2],
        [3,4,5],
        [6,7,8],
        [0,4,8],
        [2,4,6],
        [0,3,6],
        [1,4,7],
        [2,5,8],
    ];
    combos.forEach(function(row) {
      var a = row[0], b = row[1], c = row[2];
      if(model.data[a]!="" && model.data[a]==model.data[b] && model.data[b]==model.data[c])
        game.won(model.player, row);
    });
  }
}
```

Note that you could use the same model in canvas or html-less GUI. This separation of responsibilities is matter of *framework* (like Unity) and you should use this approach even when you don't use any framework - or your game quickly becomes a mess.

Now good luck and let's see if you can add the tied game functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me out a lot! :)